# Command-line tool(s) or info for building a PDF report

Tags: windows, pdf, reporting, latex

I'm trying to write a script that takes as its input one PDF file containing a header block, plus one multi-page PDF file containing black and white vector graphics plus a little text, and outputs another PDF file where each page in the output consists of the header block over (or under or next to) a grid of six cells, and each cell contains a reduced-size copy of one page from the multi-page input file (perhaps cropped a bit).

The closest I've gotten was using the "montage" command of ImageMagick.  The problem I had was that ImageMagick rasterizes all its input before it does anything else, and so by the time I got up to even just four or five pages of output at the resolution I need, it was taking my workstation over a minute to do the work, and the resulting file was 130MB, which is a ridiculous waste of resources.  And even then, the line drawings suffered from aliasing.

I've looked into Ghostscript, but it seems oriented toward experienced electronic typesetting professionals.  There isn't even a book available to pay for--just a cryptic, 20-page whitepaper that seems intended for people who already know how to use Ghostscript.  I'd rather not spend a week learning the finer points of GS9 Color Management and the LaTeX format only to find out that Ghostscript can't do what I'm looking for.  So, am I at least on the right track?  QPDF was too limited in its feature set and MuTool is meant for a different problem domain--unless I'm mistaken.

The platform is a Windows server. I couldn't say what the budget might be. This is an oddball project-let that's part of a much larger CAD/CAM integration project I'm doing. It's fairly low priority--or at least, it will be until the boss sees how much we're spending on paper ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) pro & server. *(The pair will cost you $3.99).*

- The pro edition is a GUI that allows a lot of control
- The server edition is the command line back end of the pro-edition.

They will allow you to:

1. Merge PDF Documents or Collate PDF Page Scans
2. Split PDF Pages into a New Document
3. Rotate PDF Documents or Pages
4. Decrypt Input as Necessary (Password Required)
5. Encrypt Output as Desired
6. Fill PDF Forms with X/FDF Data and/or Flatten Forms
7. Generate FDF Data Stencils from PDF Forms
8. **Apply a Background Watermark or a Foreground Stamp**
9. Report PDF Metrics, Bookmarks and Metadata
10. Add/Update PDF Bookmarks or Metadata
11. Attach Files to PDF Pages or the PDF Document
12. Unpack PDF Attachments
13. **Burst a PDF Document into Single Pages**
14. Uncompress and Re-Compress Page Streams
15. Repair Corrupted PDF (Where Possible)

For more flexibility but a steeper learning curve you can also look at [ReportLab](https://www.reportlab.com/) where you will find both commercial and [open source](https://www.reportlab.com/opensource/) solutions. *If you would like to go the open source solution I can recommend Michael Driscolls book [ReportLab PDF Processing with Python](https://leanpub.com/reportlab) as a great primer.*

N.B. Both PDFtk & python+ReportLab are cross platform so OS shouldn't be an issue.